# Dynamic size of QTreeWidget in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreewidget

I got a QTreewidget, which i want to be as small as possible, with probably only one branch. But i want the size to change accordingly to how that expands or collapses. As well as start out with a size that fits the filled part of the widget.

I make the QTreewidget by adding QTreeWidgetItems, which got the TreeWidget as parent, and then making QTreeWidgetItems again which got the above QTreeWidgetItem as parent.

Right now, it starts like left image, but i want it to start like the right one.(which is what the minimum size is, when you resize the window.)

[image: Unwanted] [image: Wanted]

- How can i make it resize to the minimum size at start?
- Also, how can i resize it, say it i resize it when the indented checkboxes are gone(hidden), so that takes even less space. Right now, the minimum size is still what it is, when those are visible.
- Bonus: When i changed the style, the minimum size got smaller and made me get scrollbars at minimumsize, despite not knowing what i changed, as it only happens when i change the stylesheet.

On request, here's the code, it's a whole lot of mess, as it's just work in progress. Here's the class i made for making the tree.

```
class paramTree(QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, Options: dict):
        super().__init__()
        self.setExpandsOnDoubleClick(False)
        self.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.setRootIsDecorated(False)

        self.Main = self.makeOption(Options['name'], self, Options['state'],0,Options['tooltip'])

        self.Options=[]
        if Options['options'] is not None:
            print(Options['options'])
            for number, choice in enumerate(Options['options']):
                if Options['Active option'] == number:
                    sub = self.makeOption(choice, self.Main,True,1)
                    sub.setFlags(sub.flags() ^ Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
                else:
                    sub = self.makeOption(choice, self.Main,False,1)
                self.Options.append(self.indexFromItem(sub))

    def makeOption(name, parent, checkstate, level=0, tooltip=None):
        mainItem = QTreeWidgetItem(parent,[name])
        if tooltip:
            mainItem.setToolTip(0,tooltip)
        if checkstate:
            mainItem.setCheckState(0, Qt.Checked)
        else:
            mainItem.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        mainItem.setExpanded(True)

        return mainItem
```

This is just put in a widget in images above. The class takes a dict, which has info for name/options/tooltip and a list with names, that end up making the sub checkboxes. This is done 4 times, so 4 treewidgets.

Also, here's a dict that can be passed to the class, to make it. Though, not all of it is used.

```
optiondict={
        "Active option": 1,
        "Command": "",
        "dependency": None,
        "name": "Convert to audio",
        "options": [
            "mp3",
            "aac",
            "flac"
        ],
        "state": True,
        "tooltip": "Text here"
    }
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: The size shown at the beginning does not depend on QTreeWidget but depends on the layout.

Comment: @eyllanesc Added the code. I used a QVBoxLayout to add the custom QTreeWidget, but adding stretch, before or after, does nothing to the overall shape on creation.

Comment: You could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @eyllanesc Reduced the code size, added a example settings dict. All that is needed is to make it, and add it to a layout, and show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layouts set the sizes, they take the recommended value through the `sizeHint()` function of the widgets, but this size does not match what you want.

As in your case you only want to reduce the height of the widget, we must set the minimum height with `minimumHeight()`, instead the width we set it with the recommended value with the help of the function `sizeHint()`.

```
self.resize(self.sizeHint().width(), self.minimumHeight())
```

Example:

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        optiondict={
        "Active option": 1,
        "Command": "",
        "dependency": None,
        "name": "Convert to audio",
        "options": [
        "mp3",
        "aac",
        "flac"
        ],
        "state": True,
        "tooltip": "Text here"
        }
        for i in range(4):
            w = paramTree(optiondict)
            self.layout().addWidget(w)
        self.resize(self.sizeHint().width(), self.minimumHeight())
```

[image]

Comment: This works indeed. I did however note 2 things. MinimumHeight is 0. And when changing the stylesheet, the minimum height is still 0, but the actual window is not as big, making scrollbars where it shouldn't have been without setting a stylesheet. I will need to look into that. For now, i manually set minimum size.

Comment: Does the code you have structured similar to the example, ie after assigning the layouts ?, you talk about stylesheet but do not show any, so I can not help you.

Comment: No need for any help :) I got it solved. I just mentioned it, as it was confusing how stylesheet changes(not on the treewidget itself) affected minimumHeight. Apparently, the width of the scrollbar does that. So i needed to change a few thing. I also ended up making a different thing to the answer, as i found out it wouldn't fit well when the size of the QTreeWidgets wasn't the same. I probably am going to make an answer going into detail about what i did, since it also addresses the size change one expand/collapse.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that addresses both points (Smallest possible size, and dynamic size change)

It requires a bit of work, some excluded from the simplified code i have in the example. But in essence, i have a function which checks the subcheckboxes for exclusivity. So i use the setData function to define if it's a parent checkbox, or a child checkbox. (subcheckbox) I'm sure there's an easier way, but i'm new at this...

Using the exclusivity function, i checks if it's parent or child. If it's a child, it runs through them, and gets the amount of parents and children. Then i just use each value and multiply with the size of a parent/child item. And then set the heigth from that. If a parent is collapsed, then it's cildren are not included in the calculation of size. Then i simply recalculate the size after each parent item changes.

This allows for smallest possible size, as well as dynamic resizing upon expansion/collapse.